Device Module Appears Disconnected in Azure IoT Hub Despite Updating Connection String
I am currently learning about Azure IoT Device Update and have been following this tutorial to send updates over IoT Hub.
Install and configure the Device Update agent
The Device Update agent runs on every device that's managed by Device Update. For this tutorial, we'll configure it to run as a simulator so that we can see how an update may be applied to a device without actually changing the device's configuration.

On your IoT device, add the Microsoft package repository and then add the Microsoft package signing key to your list of trusted keys.
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/multiarch/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb  


Install the Device Update agent .deb packages.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install deviceupdate-agent



Open the agent's configuration file.
sudo nano /etc/adu/du-config.json



However, my device module is not showing as 'connected' in the Azure portal and appears as 'disconnected' instead. I have already updated the connection string in the /etc/adu/du-config.json file as mentioned in the tutorial and saved the changes. Can anyone provide pointers on what might be causing this issue or suggest ways to debug it? Thanks in advance.

what your error while following the above doc

The issue seems to be with your device Connection.Check the below steps to  update the connection string and update the  device Updates .

Follow this GitHub to connect /disconnect to IoT hub module. Always IOT hub remains disconnected till you connect with EFLOW (or) code like c#, python etc.

Create an Iot Hub and Device Update for IoT Hub.




Add Device Update Administrator role  for  Device Update.



Navigate to your Azure IoT Hub => select Access Control (IAM) => chooseAdd role assignment. add  the role IoT Hub Data Contributor



Ensure that the IoT Hub Data Contributor role appears under Role Assignments after selecting Azure Device Update.

I followed this MSDoc to  Install and configure the Device Update agent.

wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/multiarch/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb 
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb 
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb ```




Update du-config.json file contents with connection string as below

{
  "schemaVersion": "1.1",
  "aduShellTrustedUsers": [
    "adu",
    "do"
  ],
  "iotHubProtocol": "mqtt",
  "compatPropertyNames":"manufacturer,model,location,language" <property values must be in lower case only>,
  "manufacturer": <device info manufacturer>,
  "model": < device info model >,
  "agents": [
    {
      "name": < agent name>,
      "runas": "adu",
      "connectionSource": {
        "connectionType": "string", //or “AIS”
        "connectionData": < Azure IoT device connection string >
      },
      "manufacturer": < device property manufacturer >,
      "model": < device property model >,
      "additionalDeviceProperties": {
        "location": "usa",
        "environment": "development"
      }
    }
  ]
}


To install and configure the Device Update agent, follow these steps.

In IoT Hub Updates choose the adu-update-image-raspberrypi3.swu and TutorialImportManifest_Sim.importmanifest.json  files, then selectUpload.


After Uploading , check the status in  Groups and Deployments.


